# What does it mean by "readily evident"?

Tags: meaning, american-english, terminology, british-english

There is often information “hidden” in the data that is not readily evident.

What does it mean by "readily evident"?

Comment: Readily could mean "quickly" and "easily". "Not readily evident" means it takes more time for the data to be evident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has somewhat come up in another post: [If "clearly evident" is redundant, what word or phrase suggests being indisputable but not readily apparent?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189862/if-clearly-evident-is-redundant-what-word-or-phrase-suggests-being-indisputab)

But I Googled around for the idea, and it seems like "readily evident" is used a bit, but not that commonly. It seems idiomatic to me. In a technological environment, I would assume that "readily evident" means that it wouldn't require extra analyzing or computing. Information that can be concluded from data can sometimes only be concluded after complex analyzing. Perhaps "readily evident" means that the conclusion can be very easily reached by any reader.