# Is the phrase “refreshing respite” redundant?

Tags: redundancy

Is the phrase “refreshing respite” redundant?

Refreshing is defined as “serving to refresh or reinvigorate someone”

Respite is defined as “a short period of rest or relief”

Using it in a sentence: “It was a refreshing respite between Boston and Rhodes Island.”

Comment: Why would this matter at all?

Comment: A respite is usually something that *one party* has from a situation. "Boston had a respite from Rhode Island's attacks when their key player was substituted."

Comment: @tchrist I’m not sure how to answer your question, I’m just curious. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Many questions along the lines of "Is XXX YYY redundant?" assume that redundancy is somehow a bad thing or a superfluous thing or a sloppy thing. They presuppose that a "yes" answer would somehow mean something is "wrong" that needs to be "corrected" by one or another piece being removed.  As [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/189840) observes, “So though it's redundant, it does not mean it's not a useful and acceptable way to express an idea more *clearly*.”  [See the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redundancy_%28linguistics%29) about all this.

Comment: There is no reason that a time period, whether a respite or not, cannot be qualified by adjectives. Think about it. You might have a short period of rest (respite) and it could be very noisy. I often think of respite as bringing relief from something. Like noise, fatigue, annoyance, etc.

Comment: Not all respites are refreshing.

Comment: @tchrist thank you for the clarification that makes sense, I definitely was presupposing that the redundancy would be bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the phrase “refreshing respite” redundant? Refreshing is defined as “serving to refresh or reinvigorate someone”. Respite is defined as “a short period of rest or relief.”

"Respite" can be qualified. There is *inadequate* respite; *physical but not mental* respite; *welcome* respite; *little* respite, etc.

"A short period of rest or relief' does not contain within the nuance or information: 'serving to refresh or reinvigorate someone [or something]'

You can omit any adjective, but, in doing so, you will probably omit information.

Answer (score 2):

Etymology of respite goes to "refrain from action" (as might allow a moment for reflection - https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/respite). No doubt there are many emotions one might experience during such moments, depending on what you are refraining from (scarfing down an endless meal, writing a poem, making passionate love, trying to prove a mathematical theorem, running from a bear [where one might indulge in a risky respite]). Thus, many possible descriptors of respite, many of which might be quite informative.